# How to programmatically select top row of JQGrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, selection, row

How does one programmatically select the top row of a JQGrid. I want to have the top row already selected when it is opened on the page. My grid is sorted by a descriptive column so the first row's id could be any number. I know the method  to use I just don't know how to get the rowid for the top (first) row. The method is:

```
jQuery("#mygrid").setSelection(rowid, true);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Or, without using the jqGrid API, you should be able to retrieve the top row by navigating the DOM:

```
var top_rowid = $('#mygrid tbody:first-child tr:first').attr('id');
```

Comment: This would actually be worse than just using the jqGrid API, as it would be slower to acquire.

jqGrid has the row ids stored in a readily available variable, whereas this way opens and parses the DOM when it doesn't need to be opened.

Comment: If there is a header row this version does not work. The correct selector for both cases:


    var top_rowid = $('#mygrid tbody:first-child tr.jqgrow:first').attr('id');

Comment: the above did not work it gave me the id of the row with class jqfirstrow which is undefined.The answer below $("#mygrid").getDataIDs()[0] worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

The answer above was close, but the case was off. It should be:

```
$("#mygrid").getDataIDs()[0];
```

That should work properly.

Answer (score 8):

jqGrid supports a `setSelection` method it just needs to be called correctly:

```
var grid = jQuery("#mygrid"),
    ids = grid.jqGrid("getDataIDs");
if(ids && ids.length > 0)
    grid.jqGrid("setSelection", ids[0]);
```

Comment: I can select this but it does not allow keyboard navigation via the new 4.0 api. any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

```
 $("#mygrid").getDataIDs()[0]; // SO now requires 30 characters, so....
```

Comment: try as I might - I could not get this api call to work. Navigating thru the dom however as suggested below worked. Thanks anyway - not sure why the call fails - but it does for me.

Comment: I think the syntax for jqGrid 3.6 has changed to something like: `$('#mygrid').jqGrid('getDataIDs');`, however this threw an error for me when I tried it using Firebug against the online v3.6 demos.

Comment: Sam, the old syntax works, as well as the new API. I gave the former since it works on old and new.

Comment: my grid setup to get this to work had the following event def:

            gridComplete: function() {
                var top_rowid = $('#mygridtbody:first-child tr:first').attr('id');
                $("#mygrid").setSelection(top_rowid, true);
            },

Answer (score 1):

Complete code when table have header row:

```
var top_rowid = $('#mygrid tr:nth-child(2)').attr('id'); 
$("#mygrid").setSelection(top_rowid, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used the following:

```
var grid = $('#list');
grid.jqGrid({
    ...
    gridComplete: function() {
        var ids = grid.jqGrid("getDataIDs");
        if(ids.length > 0) { 
            grid.jqGrid("setSelection", ids[0]);
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a header row, try this:

```
var top_rowid = $('#mygrid tbody:first-child tr:nth-child(2)').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have header row try this :

`$('#tb_par tbody:first-child tr:nth-child(2)').trigger("click");`

If not than :

`$('#mygrid tbody:first-child tr:first').trigger("click");`

It will directly trigger click event of the JqGrid.